# Automatically reshape pandas DataFrame as columns of different lengths are added to existing DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

[image]

When I try to add a list of values (of arbitrary length) to one of the columns I get an error:

```
mydf['a','curr(A)'] = [6,6,6,6,6]
```

or

```
mydf['a','curr(A)'] = [6,6]
```

gives the following error:

```
"ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"
```

But this works:

```
mydf['a','curr(A)'] = [6,6,6]
```

How can I add an arbitrary number of entries to a column and pad the DataFrame with NaN's when necessary? Is there a parameter I can set when defining the DataFrame to do this padding automatically?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `mydf['a','curr(A)'] = [6,6,6]` is the same as `mydf['a','curr(A)'] = 6`.. Or can the values be different?

Comment: The values and number of values I would like to add to each column are arbitrary: for example [5.5,-34e-5, 177] or [-2, 3, 6, 7.18, 10000000, -4e22]

Comment: @fsimonjetz I think he is looking to add a column of different length to the df

Comment: Yup @fthomson that's what I'm going for. But not adding a new column. Just adding entries to an existing column. Is it just me, or does it seem like everything with pandas is harder than it should be?

Comment: @Crawdad_Buckwheat it takes some time getting used to coming from excel or similar spreadsheet software. However you are able to do so much more with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be something with concat

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    0:[1,2,3],
    1:[1,2,3],
    2:[4,5,6]
})

row = pd.Series([6,6,6,6])
pd.concat([df2,row], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Results:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   1.0 4.0
1   2   2.0 5.0
2   3   3.0 6.0
3   6   NaN NaN
4   6   NaN NaN
5   6   NaN NaN
6   6   NaN NaN
```

I don't think you are able to do this by just assigning the values to a column

Comment: I think this is the right track but It gave me an error because I'm using multi Indexing (for example ('b', 'volt(V)'). Here's the error I got when I tried your example code: '''NotImplementedError: Can only union MultiIndex with MultiIndex or Index of tuples, try mi.to_flat_index().union(other) instead.'''

Answer (score 0):

Turn the sequence into another df (with the same column names) and then use [`.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns).

```py
df_val = pd.DataFrame({('a', 'curr(a)'): [6, 6, 6]})
df_final = mydf.combine_first(df_val)
```

Comment: I tried adding a list of 6 elements this way.  It filled up the 3 preexisting positions  in ('a','curr(A') but Ignored the additional elements I told it to add and didn't reshape the df.

Comment: I assumed that's what you wanted.. So in case the list is longer than the original df, you need *everything else* to be nan?

Comment: Yes I want to add columns of different sizes and resize the df as needed. So if the list is longer than the original df I want to pad the empty spaces with NaN. Sorry I wasn't clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to solve my specific problem but it only works because I have all the columns I want in the dataframe ahead of time.

```
# 2 pairs of lists I want to use as column data.
mydf = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[-3,4,-5,6,12]]) 
mydf = mydf.transpose() # Transpose to go from 4 rows to 4 columns.
# Create multilevel index with 4 indices
multi_idx =  multi_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'],['curr(A)','volt(V)']]) 
for col in mydf.columns: # loop through to rename each column 
    mydf = mydf.rename(columns = {col : multi_idx[col]})
```

It works, but it seems like there must be a simpler way to do this.

Thanks for your help everyone!